# How to set header size of UICollectionView in swift 5.1?

Tags: ios, swift

In the lower swift I can use this function to set the size

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
}
```

but it is not work in swift 5.1

what function is fine in swift 5.1?

besides I have already inherited the UICollectionViewController

Answer (score 2):

You have to add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, hope this helps you :)

```
class SampleViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
   }

}
```

Comment: it says Redundant conformance of 'SampleViewController' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource' since my controller implemented UICollectionViewController

Answer (score 0):

**Return Header or Footer height & width**

```
extension YourCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100)
   }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

**Return UICollectionView Header or Footer**

```
class YourCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter) {
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", for: indexPath)
        // Customize footerView here
        return footerView
    } else if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader) {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", for: indexPath)
        // Customize headerView here
        return headerView
    }
    fatalError()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I find the method of `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` like @Raj Sharma and @Aira Samson said is depreted

I have specify the layout of the header and footer in the `prepare()` function and return it to the `layoutAttributesForItem` function and the `layoutAttributesForElements` function.

the order is :

- prepare() to caculate the attributes
- return layoutAttributes that is    cached.

this is in swift 5.1.